# Why useSWR always refresh even though the key stored in cache?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

Why useSWR always refresh even though the key is stored in the cache?
[image]

I print all cache from ````const { cache } = useSWRConfig(); ```, when a certain call is requested before, it will request again when I repeat this action on the web. Why does this happen? how can I fix it?

using: react, next.js, ssr

Answer (score 2):

Because it could have changed.

If you know the resource to be immutable, i.e. that you absolutely never need to automatically fetch it again, [disable automatic revalidation](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#disable-automatic-revalidations).

```
useSWR(key, fetcher, {
  revalidateIfStale: false,
  revalidateOnFocus: false,
  revalidateOnReconnect: false
})
```

(which is equivalent to `useSWRImmutable(key, fetcher)` (SWR 1.0+))

Comment: No, it's not changed, like '/api/folder/xxxxx', with same folderId, it will also refetch. for my understanding, SWR need first check whether this key in cache, if not, refetch, if yes, use cache. but SWR seems not that logic, so what's the meaning of SWR cache, I am confused....